# Is the routing on an elasticsearch cluster automatic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using totally default ES settings and have a node up and running on my local network.  So, I start with a node on:

```
http://10.10.1.1:9200
```

And get...

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://10.10.1.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 10,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

I start up a second instance on

```
http://10.10.1.2:9200
```

Now, it works, they see each other, and the number of nodes increases, there is remarkable ES magic happening automatically, great!  But is it the case that I can now still ping only...

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://10.10.1.1:9200/myindex/mytype/1'
```

...and the requests will be directed to /both/ nodes?  That is: do I need to change any additional settings to get the first endpoint to distribute work to the second server when it's overburdened, or does the first one automatically become a kind of router distributing tasks to the rest of the cluster?

I'd like to understand what configuration I need so that I may start n instances while pinging only a single url and have the work distributed optimally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's automatic - generally you don't need to do anything further.

An index is broken up into shards and the shards distributed over the nodes you have. When you add a node ES will automatically re-distribute the shards.

Data is assigned to a shard in an index based on a hash of the _id. In this request:

```
curl -XGET 'http://10.10.1.1:9200/myindex/mytype/1'
```

You've specified the _id (1) so ES can forward the request directly to the shard that contains the data.  If you haven't specified an _id (i.e. you're querying for data) then the node to which you sent the request will:

1. forward the request onto all shards
2. wait for their responses
3. aggregate the responses
4. send back to the requesting client

See [Routing a document](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html) for more information.